# Is it possible to extract the correct unicode values of a text from a PDF or HTML files with embedded fonts?

Tags: html, pdf, unicode, fonts

This is my first question here, so I apologize if I am breaking any guidelines.
I found similar questions to this one, but none of what I could find tried these methods.

I am trying to programmatically read the text from a PDF file with embedded fonts (copying or reading directly just shows random characters).

[You can find a sample PDF here.](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8bc5650b1a2a89724202266298207be420200118083435/804a04)

After uncompressing the PDF using qpdf, I could find a CMap and a ToUnicode method. However, I couldn't understand them.
I tried extracting the font from the PDF using mutool, and then generating a CMap using ttx. It worked but the CMap wasn't helpful, as it only matched the unicode values to themselves.

[You can find the ttf and ttx files here.](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/f3ea164d6ef9e06f5a9c4e7b08f2b54620200118085707/8f0d9f)

I converted the PDF to HTML using PDF2HTMLEX, it was converted and rendered correctly, but the text still showed rubbish when I tried to copy it. I also tried extracting the font-face and generating a CMap from it, but this time, the CMap just mapped the Unicode values to ISO values.

[You can find the HTML and the embedded fonts here.](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/61aba1ce30448ad474d29bdd9d02973720200118090321/2d9ede)

So my question is, given this current progress, is it at all possible to write a program which automatically maps the characters in the text to their unicode values and then reads the text correctly?

Thank you in advance for your replies.

EDIT: 
I've also tried OCRs, but they are not efficient and accurate with Arabic text. 
Also, if the Arabic text cannot be highlighted, please use another PDF viewer. (e.g Google Chrome).
I did write a program which could extract everything from the PDF as text, but I had to create the character mappings manually.

Comment: The Arabic writing in the PDF is not text, only graphics. I have [highlighted the text existing in the PDF, it consists only of the digits and colons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfLah.png). The PDF author either chose to remove the text parts or the Arabic writing was typeset as graphics only in the first place. ––– Try [optical character recognition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition#Character_recognition).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @daxim.
The Arabic writing is text, though some PDF viewers may not be able to highlight it. I use Google Chrome and it highlights everything just fine. I also wrote a program which correctly extracts everything from the table programmatically, but I had to manually create the character mappings.
As for the OCRs, I did try them, but they don't meet the efficiency and accuracy which I want.

Comment: @daxim Which PDF viewer did you use for highlighting? Using Adobe Reader or Chrome on Windows I get a different view: All text (except in the logo) is highlighted.

Comment: @EinRobot A PDF supporting text extraction would supply a good **ToUnicode** mapping or an **Encoding** that allows to derive such a mapping. If it does not (like your sample document), it *may* be possible to read Unicode values for glyphs from the embedded font, but those information are not required in font programs embedded in PDFs, so they may be missing, too. In case of the font program embedded in your example document *most* embedded glyphs have an associated Unicode value but not all do. A good font processing library should allow extracting that information.